# Better solution for subscriptions redundancy

Tags: rxjs, angular7, ngrx, ngrx-store

What I'm trying to do:

- A decouple service that subscribes to multiple NGRX **Store selectors**
- This decouple service defines **BehaviourSubjects** corrsponding to each Store selector
- **Store selector subscription emit their values to the corresponding BehaviourSubjects defined on this service**
- **Note:** This service is supposed to decouple the store from other component, doing stuff with store emitted value on the way to the components, so exposing the store subscriptions directly to components is not an option.

At first I managed with the following pattern of subscription:

```
const assignmentImportanceTypes$ = this.store.pipe(select(getAssignmentImportanceTypes), skipWhile(types => !types));
    const assignmentImportanceTypesSub = assignmentImportanceTypes$.subscribe((assignmentImportanceTypes) => {
        this.assignmentImportances_value = assignmentImportanceTypes;
        this.assignmentImportances.next(assignmentImportanceTypes);
    });
    const assignmentTypes$ = this.store.pipe(select(getAssignmentTypes), skipWhile(types => !types));
    const assignmentTypesSub = assignmentTypes$.subscribe((assignmentTypes) => {
        this.assignmentTypes_value = assignmentTypes;
        this.assignmentTypes.next(assignmentTypes);
    });
    const assignmentStatusesTypes$ = this.store.pipe(select(getAssignmentStatusesTypes), skipWhile(types => !types));
    const assignmentStatusesTypesSub = assignmentStatusesTypes$.subscribe((assignmentStatusesTypes) => {
        this.assignemntStatus_value = assignmentStatusesTypes;
        this.assignemntStatus.next(assignmentStatusesTypes);
    });
```

I then didnt like the redundancy of this, so I refactored the previous to the following, creating a model to loop over and a loop that subscribes to each selector.

The model looks as follows:

```
assignmentStoreSelectors = [
    {
        selector: getAssignmentImportanceTypes, // Store selector
        subject: this.assignmentImportances, // BehaviourSubject on service
        lastValue:null 
    },
    {
        selector: getAssignmentStatusesTypes, // Store selector
        subject: this.assignemntStatus, //BehaviourSubject on service
        lastValue:null
    },
    {
        selector: getAssignmentTypes, // Store selector
        subject: this.assignmentTypes, //BehaviourSubject on service
        lastValue:null
    }
]
```

I then loop over this model and subscribe to each selector, emitting subscription value insdie the subscription to the BehaviorSubject defined on this service:

```
this.assignmentStoreSelectors.forEach((storeSelectorObj: any) => {
        this.store.pipe(select(storeSelectorObj.selector), skipWhile(enumValue => !enumValue))
        .subscribe((enumValue) => {
            storeSelectorObj.lastValue = enumValue;
            storeSelectorObj.subject.next(enumValue);
        });
    });
```

This shortened the redundancy of the initial pattern & made it all more generic, but it brought in a model object and I feel like there should be an RXJS way of doing this that I'm not aware of.

Whats a better way to do this?
Or what is the RXJS way of doing this?

Comment: Any specific reason for a service and use BehaviorSubject? NGRX store's uses BS so you are just adding not needed complexity in your code. You should directly use your selectors in the components. To answer your question - You can use zip/forkJoin/Combinelatest depends on your need and subscribe only once.

Comment: Basicaly this service is supposed to take the store values and manipulate its data injecting it into the components after the original data was manipulated according to the service.
the reason i'm doing this is basically refactoring existing code to use the store, the existing code is the service which is injected in many place so I have to connect to this service making it a decoupling layer from the store.